# https response quite slow using NGINX for NodeJs application

Tags: node.js, nginx, google-compute-engine

enter code hereI have a web application mapped with multiple domains. One of the domain is using SSL while other one is simple.
I tried to use NGINX with nodeJs. My HTTPs response is very very slow. Please have a look at the conf file and help me to get rid of this problem.

```
upstream myserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:4502;
        server 127.0.0.1:4500;
}


server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name a.myserver.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/nodetest.log;
        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          proxy_pass http://myserver/;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }
}

server {
        listen 0.0.0:443;
        server_name myapps.com;
        access_log off;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /mnt/drives/ssl_certificates/daffodilapps/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /mnt/drives/ssl_certificates/daffodilapps/ryans-key.pem;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://myserver/;
                proxy_redirect off;
```

Comment: Just a quick one, change listen to only port without 0.0.0*. Might not be related to your issue, still worth mentioning.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/807420/nginx-and-apache-are-very-slow-as-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-app-with-socket-io
Did you find a solution?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your node.js application is not a factor, since you access it the same way in the end.  Still, you might want to validate that by doing a performance test for http vs. https against a static page.  If it turns out that nginx SSL performance is still poor, you might try changing the cipher suites that nginx offers, per the advice in [Nginx Performance Tuning for SSL](http://techsamurais.com/?p=1384).

Also, you don't list what kind of VM you are using, but you might also try upgrading to a non-shared-core VM if you're currently on a f1/g1.  The extra (and dedicated) CPU should help SSL performance, which is also mentioned in the article when they switched from a micro to a regular EC2 VM.